# Secure dynamic binding of fields in hql

Tags: hql

I'd like to generate hql queries in which both the persisted object variables as well as their values can be chosen at runtime (for the purposes of updating individual fields.) i.e. Something like the following:

```
String field, value;
String queryString = "update User u set u."+field+" = "+ value +" where (someCondition)"
```

This code works, but is not secure against hql injection. Trying to do this using the named parameter method

```
Update user u set :field = :value where (someCondition)
```

throws a querySyntaxException:

```
"expecting IDENT, found ":";
```

I get a similar error trying positional binding with a query string `"... u.?=? ..."`

Answer (score 0):

On the offchance that anyone else is searching for how to do this:
I've realised *why* it's probably not possible to guard against hql injection of the field name: the end user should not be aware of my object variable names [*facepalm].

So I can solve the problem by freely concatentating my string for the member variable, but use a named parameter to securely insert the value of that variable (which the user does provide.)

```
String queryString = "update User u set u." +  field + " = :value where (someCondition)";
```

etc.